# Django Database Error

Tags: django

I've been trying to fix this for the past hour but I have no idea what I left out. This is a first time project with no previous data. However, when I try to add data through the admin panel I get the error below:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/judge/event/

relation "judge_event" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "judge_event"
                             ^

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8012/admin/judge/event/
Django Version:     1.4.3
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    

relation "judge_event" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "judge_event"
```

My model for reference :

```
class Event(models.Model):
    competition_start = models.DateTimeField() 
    competitors = models.ManyToManyField('Picture')
    results = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=20)

class Picture(models.Model):
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=10)
    score_RD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=10)
    rated = models.BooleanField()
    last_competed = models.DateTimeField() 
    competition = models.OneToOneField(Event)
```

I triple checked all my notes and didn't notice that I did anything differently.

Should "judge_event" be "judge_Event"?

Comment: Have you changed the models since the first time you ran `syncdb`?

Comment: Mmm...not that I noticed, but if it is an issue with 'judge_Event'; how would I change my database to reflect this change without using SQL?

Comment: I suggest you drop you the database and syncdb again. This is the only safe way your database complies to your models (unless you use a migration tool like south, which I don't recommend if you are just starting with django).

Comment: When I try to reset my db; it freezes at the following screen. sudo python manage.py reset login 
You have requested a database reset.
This will IRREVERSIBLY DESTROY any data for
the "login" application in the database "postgres".
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a change to your models that was *destructive* (like adding a foreign key). `syncdb` does not make any destructive changes to the schema.

So, you need to drop your tables and then do syncdb so the new schema is correctly applied.

There are applications that support such changes *called migrations*.

One of the most popular of these is [`south`](http://south.aeracode.org/). Once you are more familiar with django you can start using it.

Comment: I am trying to use South but it freezes whenever I try to migrate databases and I'm trying to start fresh by running ./manage.py reset myapp but that doesn't work either. It freezes after I say 'yes' allow for the reset

Comment: If you are just starting out, don't complicate matters with south. Just delete the file (if you are using sqlite) and then run syncdb.